# laravel Eloquent Relationship query with whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables as bellow

user:

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | abc@... |
| 2 | xyz | xyz@... |
| 3 | abx | abx@... |

books:

| id | user_name | book | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc:x1 | book1 | 10 |
| 2 | xyz:x2 | book1 | 20 |
| 3 | abc:x5 | book3 | 30 |
| 4 | ab:x2 | book1 | 10 |

If you notice that my 2nd table field user_name have user_name of user table plus **:x** and number

> maybe this didn't make sense but this is my project requirements

Now when I want to query some user with books like If I search a user with ID (1)
it should give me records of 1 & 3 because of user_name

I tried this

```php
$user = USER::with('books')
          whereHas('books', function ($query) {
             $query->where('user_name', 'like', 'name:%');
})->get();
```

Also, I tried this

```php
USER::with('books')
    ->whereHas('books', function ($query) use ($name) {
       $query->where('user_name', 'like', $name . ':%');
     })
```

Also not working.

**Also how to get 3rd extra column value after :x**

Also, is this possible to write this query in model?

Thanks

Comment: please post the user model (in particular the books relation)

Comment: relation is as bellow
in user model
public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Books::class,'user_name','name');
    }

Comment: relation is fine as I can query records with exact math

Comment: R u sure? There is no way that mysql relations works without a exact match between the two columns, so what you are doing can’t be modeled using a relation

Comment: What you can do is to create a scope in the model, and do the query there, but you wont have access to everything you can do with a relation

Comment: Thanks , Yes scope is also ok but how can I get this result with scope please

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you that you should always store normalized data in database irrespective of the presentation layer of the data. The data can be transformed in your desired form at query level or in the app itself.

So you should introduce 2 columns in your books table

- user_id
- sequence

like

---

| id | user_id | sequence | book | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | book1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | book1 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | book3 | 30 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | book1 | 10 |

This way you can filter out the users easily and you can apply filter on user books also. To construct the user name you can use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators) and a virtual attribute in your book model which will construct the user name for you like

```
class Book extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['user_name'];

    protected $with = ['user'];
   
    public function getUserNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user->name .":x". $this->sequence;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

`$appends` will hold the custom attributes for your models and the accessor method will construct a user name using the `user()` relation. So its important if you load books then you should also eager the related users so that in accessor `$this->user->name` will have the name from user table otherwise it will be empty, For this you can use `$with` property in your model which will intimate that related user should be loaded whenever books are loaded.

Now you can get the user with specific id as

```
User::with('books')->find(1);
```

Or books by the name of user as

```
Book::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($name) {
       $query->where('name', 'like', $name);
     });
```

Or books by the name of user and with the number after x that is sequence

```
Book::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($name, $sequence) {
       $query->where('name', 'like', $name);
     })->where('sequence', $sequence);
```